# How to get number of days between two given dates in Scala

Tags: scala, date, jodatime, days

i tried to get all date between two given dates , but unable to get.

I have tried like this.

```
val dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
var start = dateformat.parse("2020-10-01")
var end = dateformat.parse("2020-10-12")

val days = Days.daysBetween(start, end)
val months = Months.monthsBetween(start, end)
```

But i am getting daysBetween not found?

Edit: my imports are:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.Months;
```

Comment: how did you import Days and Months?

Comment: @mck like as import org.joda.time.DateTime
    import org.joda.time.Days
    import org.joda.time.Months

Comment: Thank you for sharing your imports, it’s helpful. It’s always best to add new information in the question itself, not in comment, so we have everything on one place.

Comment: When you can use Joda-Time, I recommend you go all-in on Joda-Time and avoid mixing `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` in. `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`  are poorly designed, which was  why Joda-Time was developed in the first place.

Comment: FYI, *Joda-Time* is now winding down, in maintenance-mode. Its creator went on to produce the *java.time* classes now built into Java. Consider migrating when convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix java time and joda time. Create the datetime using joda as well.

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.{Days,Months}

val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
var start = formatter.parseDateTime("2020-10-01")
var end = formatter.parseDateTime("2020-10-12")

val days = Days.daysBetween(start, end)
val months = Months.monthsBetween(start, end)
```

Comment: what when i try to print dates its print like 2020-10-12T00:00:00.000+05:30 , how i can convert it to any dateformat

Comment: @Dev use  `start.toDate`

Comment: The answer is fine. I disagree about the last comment. When using Joda-Time, stay away from the `Date` class, it’s poorly designed and long outdated. To print the `DateTime` in a specific format, use a `DateTimeFormatter`, either the same one again or a seoncd one.

Answer (score 5):

### java.time

For the sake of completeness here’s the java.time version of the same code. java.time is the modern Java date and time API and the successor of Joda-Time. You will have to translate from my Java code yourself, though.

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("2020-10-01");
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("2020-10-12");

long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start, end);

System.out.format("Between %s and %s are %d days or %d months%n",
        start, end, days, months);
```

Output:

> Between 2020-10-01 and 2020-10-12 are 11 days or 0 months

The Joda-Time home page says:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
> No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
> to `java.time` (JSR-310).

### What went wrong in your code?

> But i am getting daysBetween not found?

It’s not that Scala cannot find `Days.daysBetween()`. Your `start` and `end` have type `Date`, and what the message means is that Scala cannot find a `daysBetween` method that accepts two `Date` arguments. Instead you will need to pass two objects of type `ReadableInstant` (or `ReadablePartial`, but that’s a different story). Since Joda’s own `DateTime` class implements the `ReadableInstant` interface, you’ll be fine with two of those as shown in the other answer.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Joda-Time Home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)